# Customising and manipulating Local Policies in non-AD network

Tags: windows, group-policy, security-policy

I'm running a small LAN mainly of clients running Windows 8.1 Pro/Enterprise. I've used GPEdit/SecPol MSC and equivalent reg keys to manipulate local policies and items listed as being able to be set through group Policy (if it were a domain), but I'd like to educate myself and use Local Policies more effectively.

Ideally my aim is to add a custom GP/SecPol/? MSC section containing just the policies/settings I find useful, so they are all in one place and can be imported as a single files for "default" or "custom" settings, much as one would with .reg files but with the extra bonus of descriptions and more clarity of the options being set, hence less prone to error.

But I'm not sure how to go about doing this, and how to "dump" all existing policies to a human-readable format to see what they are actually doing internally and to modify and re-import them (if that's the correct term). Most documentation assumes a domain and isn't very helpful otherwise.

Comment: "Group Policies" can only be used on a domain, when you use gpedit.msc on a non-domain computer, you're editing the "Local Polices".  Regardless of that, as-is your question is vague and hard to discern what it is you're actually asking for help with.

Comment: Thanks, I've considerably modified the question in light of that helpful comment.  Is it clear or do i need to clarify other things more?

Comment: Secpol.msc has Export and Import features, have you tried that yet?